# Identity Server 4 email validation endpoint

Tags: identityserver4

We're currently using IdentityServer 4 as our SSO.

As part of a requirement set by our PM, an endpoint for email validation is required. Such endpoint would provide a simple functionality: validate the existence of an already registered email in our system.

This raised the concern about directory harvest attack, increasing the attack surface, etc.

Since IdentityServer does not provide such functionality out of the box, we believe for good reasons, would it be wise to add such functionality on top of the existing one (given previously mentioned concerns) or at all in the platform?

An argument that was raised was the fact that the registration form could provide identical functionality. But, server side rendered pages, making use of anti-forgery token mitigate (eliminate?) such option it appears.
In our case, the client application is Angular2 based.

Suggestions?

Comment: Who will be using the email validation endpoint? A highly trusted application? The client application?

Comment: The client application is the intended one. So if the user inserts an email that's already in use, he'll get an indicating about it.

Comment: You could add a captcha to your registration page, the client sets off a request to the server with the email and the captcha, you let the identity server check the captcha and if it's correct you can check the email against the database...

Comment: That could work if the email check was part of the full post of details for registration. In this case, it's just to provide an indication to the user so the UI do does not have a place to accommodate for that flow and UX wise it'll be inconvenient. Thanks for the suggestion though